# IntelliJ - Warning message does not appear for the condition i >= 2 when i is known

Tags: java, if-statement, intellij-idea, conditional-statements

The following program on IntelliJ

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    if (i <= 2) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

warns me "Condition 'i <= 2' is always 'true'". 
If I replace the condition with `i > 2` , I get "Condition 'i > 2' is always 'false'". Same with `i == 2`.

But if I replace it with `i >= 2` I don't have any warnings.

Why in the last case IntelliJ does not warn me that this condition is always false ?

I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.5 and the compiler used is javac in its 1.8.0_51 version.

[image]

Comment: seems like a fault in the implementation of Intellij not a Java issue. I would recommend reporting this to JetBrains.

Comment: I don't think there's any deep reason. It must just be a bug, but it's a rather strange one. If I do `int i = 5; if (i <= 2)` I don't get a warning.

Comment: Probably https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146950

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more a bug report than a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Paul Boddington said in a comment, it's actually something JetBrains forgot to implement in their algorithm, that has been [fixed a few days ago](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-community/revision/27271e99791b1c87cbcc6ca39a2cedeb1bb6a58b).

Before:

```
if (opSign == LT && comparedWith <= rangeMin) return alwaysFalse(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == LT && comparedWith > rangeMax) return alwaysTrue(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == LE && comparedWith >= rangeMax) return alwaysTrue(instruction, runner, memState);

if (opSign == GT && comparedWith >= rangeMax) return alwaysFalse(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == GT && comparedWith < rangeMin) return alwaysTrue(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == GE && comparedWith <= rangeMin) return alwaysTrue(instruction, runner, memState);
```

After:

```
if (opSign == LT && comparedWith <= rangeMin) return alwaysFalse(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == LT && comparedWith > rangeMax) return alwaysTrue(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == LE && comparedWith >= rangeMax) return alwaysTrue(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == LE && comparedWith < rangeMin) return alwaysFalse(instruction, runner, memState);

if (opSign == GT && comparedWith >= rangeMax) return alwaysFalse(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == GT && comparedWith < rangeMin) return alwaysTrue(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == GE && comparedWith <= rangeMin) return alwaysTrue(instruction, runner, memState);
if (opSign == GE && comparedWith > rangeMax) return alwaysFalse(instruction, runner, memState);
```

Corresponding issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146950

Answer (score 1):

This was brought to my attention about a week ago so its funny I saw it on here soon after too. I looked into it and its been happening as early as Intellij 10 apparently. There were a few bug fixes for it throughout all the updates but the problem has not been fixed clearly.

Here is a link where Jetbrains refers to the bug. There are multiple cases. [IDEA-84489](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+11+117.281+Release+Notes)

If its bothering you, try suppressing the warning via Alt+Enter while your cursor is over it and choose the option that says "suppress for..."